# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000); CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, create-table, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to create some tables for a database, however the following error is being raised. If I remove the *middle_name* and *last_name* fields for the actor table, the table is created, but the same error is raised for the next table.

Where exactly are the syntax errors?

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near 'middle_name VARCHAR(20)
        last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        PRIMARY K' at line 3
```

```
tables = ["""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tag (
        name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    );
""", """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS genre (
        name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    );
""", """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actor (
        first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        middle_name VARCHAR(20)
        last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY(first_name, last_name)
    );
""", """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS show_tag (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
        tag_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        show_title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY tag_name REFERENCES tag(name)
        FOREIGN KEY show_title REFERENCES show(title)
    );
""", """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS show_genre (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
        genre_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        show_title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY genre_name REFERENCES genre(name)
        FOREIGN KEY show_title REFERENCES show(title)
    );
""", """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS show_actor (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
        actor_fn VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        actor_ln VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        show_title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY (actor_fn, actor_ln) REFERENCES actor(fn, ln)
        FOREIGN KEY (show_title) REFERENCES show(title)
    );
""",
"""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS show (
        title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        view_rating VARCHAR(8)
        release_date DATE
        summary TEXT
        score DECIMAL(2, 1)
    );
"""]
```

Comment: Use commas,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: The MySQL reference for `CREatE TABLE` is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html). Check these statements carefully against it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have commas between all of the field definitions:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actor (
        first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        middle_name VARCHAR(20),
        last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY(first_name, last_name)
    );
```

Comment: There's more than that. The FOREIGN KEY column names need to be wrapped in parentheses, and the use of `show` as a table name is also causing problems.